# Homotopy equivalence of chain complexes from subcomplexes and quotient complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences, chain-complexes, extension

Let $C_1$ be a finite-dimensional chain complex over $\mathbb{C}$ coefficients. Let $S_i$ be a subcomplex of $C_1$ and let $Q_1$ be the quotient complex. Suppose $S_1$ and $Q_1$ are chain homotopy equivalent to complexes $S_2$ and $Q_2$ by specific chain maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ (with inverse $g_1$ and $g_2$), respectively. Can we show that $C_1$ is chain homotopic equivalent to some complex $C_2$ with subcomplex $S_2$ and quotient complex $Q_2$, such that the chain map $f$ restricts to $f_1$ and $f_2$?

More generally, let $C_1$ be a filtered finite-dimensional chain complex over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose the associated graded complex $gr(C_1)$ is chain homotopic to some graded chain complex $G$ via a chain homotopy $f_{gr}$. Can we show that $C_1$ is filtered chain homotopy equivalent to some filtered complex $C_2$ by a map $f$ that restricts to $f_{gr}$?

Comment: For chain complexes over a field, chain homotopy equivalence coincides with quasiisomorphism; and the fact that "$f$ induces iso on cohomology" is equivalent to "$f$ induces iso on cohomology of associated graded quotient by a complete exhaustive filtration" is an easy excercise on spectral sequences.

Comment: (cont.) So the only question is whether partial maps glue together at all to some chain map; but that's also true, because $\Bbb C$ is a field and every complex is a direct sum of its cohomology and a split exact complex.

Comment: What I'm asking is about gluing partial maps. I edit the question because the previous one is not true. Could you explain more on the gluing problem? I think it is related to some homology perturbation lemma.